# Sensitivity of a single photon detector

Tags: photons, semiconductor-physics

I want to know about the minimum receive sensitivity of single photon detector so I can make a link budget analysis of optical signal.

I am looking for minimum threshold of optical power that can easily detected by the single photon detector.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! You should tell us what you already did to try to answer your own question and where the difficulty lies.

Comment: The jargon that you are looking for to make searching easier is "*quantum efficiency*".

Comment: "*easily be detected*.   There's the rub.   You have to account for all possible sources of signal that are due to sources *other* than the signal that you are looking for (*noise*), such as thermally generated carriers.   Then you have to determine how long your detector takes to make one measurement.   All of these things have to be combined to find the minimum detectable signal.  The analysis is straightforward in most cases, but I think it's too long to set out in an answer here.  Google "optical minimum detectable power", and relate "power" to the expected rate of incident photons.

Answer (score 1):

If it can detect single photons of a given frequency, there's an *energy* threshold $h\nu$, not a power one.

Detector makers usually talk about a given probability of detection. For example:

[image]

Source: [Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5255).